# Converting a PyG graph to a NetworkX graph

Tags: nodes, networkx, data-conversion, edges, pytorch-geometric

I am trying to convert my PyG graph to a NetworkX graph using `to_networkx`

According to the [docs](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/utils.html?highlight=networkx#torch_geometric.utils.to_networkx) I can optionally pass node and edge attributes as str iterables, in addition to the Data object.

Below are by node and edge attribute lists, with values converted to strings:

```
Nodes:  ['3.3375725746154785', '2.0086510181427',..., '1.5960148572921753', '3.621992349624634']

Edges:  ['0.9940207804344958', '0.48573804411542043', ..., '0.7245483440145621', '0.24117984598949904']
```

`to_networkx` runs fine when I only pass it the Data object. However, when I also pass these attribute lists, I get the below error:

```
G[u][v][key] = values[key][i]
KeyError: '0.30194718370332896'
```

I've looked at the source code, but can't make out what it is doing. Could someone please help explain what is wrong with my attribute lists and what I need to change for them to be accepted.

What I can make out is that this error is specifically referring to my edge attributes. If I remove them, I get the following similar error related to the node attributes:

```
feat_dict.update({key: values[key][i]})
KeyError: '0.0'
```

How I construct my graph and pass it to `to_networkx`:

```
n1 = np.repeat(np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6]),5)
n2 = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4])
cat = np.stack((n1,n2), axis=0)
e = torch.tensor(cat, dtype=torch.long)
edge_index = e.t().clone().detach()
edge_attr = torch.tensor(np.random.rand(35,1))

x = torch.tensor([[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [1], [1]], dtype=torch.float)

data = Data(x=x, edge_index=edge_index.t().contiguous(), edge_attr = edge_attr)
```

Before I pass the node and edge attributes, I do the string conversion to conform to the str iterable requirment:

```
networkx_node_values = list(map(str, data.x.t()[0].tolist()))
networkx_edge_values = list(map(str, edge_attr.t()[0].tolist()))
    
networkX_graph = to_networkx(data, node_attrs = networkx_node_values, edge_attrs = networkx_edge_values)
```

Comment: Can you include a minimal reproducible example? Currently, I don't know how you called the `to_networkx` method to raise the error. It looks like you pass the values of the attributes instead of the names.

Comment: Hi @Sparky05
I have added my example. Let me know if there is anything else you need to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the names of the attributes as a list:

```
to_networkx(<PyTorchGeometricDataObject>, node_attrs=[<Name of Node Attribute 1>, <Name of Node Attributes 2>, ... ], edge_attr=[<Edge Attribute 1>, ...])
```

Or in context, based on your given minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch_geometric.data import Data
from torch_geometric.utils import to_networkx

n1 = np.repeat(np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6]),5)
n2 = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4])
cat = np.stack((n1,n2), axis=0)
e = torch.tensor(cat, dtype=torch.long)
edge_index = e.t().clone().detach()
edge_attr = torch.tensor(np.random.rand(35,1))

x = torch.tensor([[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [1], [1]], dtype=torch.float)

data = Data(x=x, edge_index=edge_index.t().contiguous(), edge_attr = edge_attr)
print(data)
# Data(edge_attr=[35, 1], edge_index=[2, 35], x=[7, 1])

networkX_graph = to_networkx(data, node_attrs=["x"], edge_attrs=["edge_attr"])

print(networkX_graph.nodes(data=True))
# [(0, {'x': 0.0}), (1, {'x': 0.0}),...
print(networkX_graph.edges(data=True))
# [(0, 0, {'edge_attr': 0.3412137594357493}), ...
```

Comment: That works! Thanks @Sparky05. Should the docs not read, "iterable as a str", instead of "iterable of str"?

Comment: Yes, probably together with a brief example this would clarify stuff.